# How to Disable Converter Under Certain Situations

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to disable the following converter when **autosize** is false. What code should I put into **do nothing** area.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Boolean), typeof(Double))]
public class ConvertAutoSize2HeightWidth : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Boolean autosize = (Boolean)value;
        if (autosize)
            return Double.NaN;
        else
            //**do nothing**
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to return [`Binding.DoNothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.donothing.aspx).

> A binding source property or a converter can return Binding.DoNothing to instruct the binding engine not to perform any action. For example, to instruct the binding engine not to transfer a value to the binding target, not to move to the next [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) in a [PriorityBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx), or not to use the **FallBackValue** or default value.